# Where can I download the Oracle Fusion Middleware Infrastructure Software?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I understand that since version 12c the *Repository Creation Utility for Oracle Database 12c* (RCU) is part of the Oracle Fusion Middleware Infrastructure Software.

This brings me to the question: Where can I download the Oracle Fusion Middleware Infrastructure Software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://edelivery.oracle.com/

Log in with your oracle.com account.

Product Pack: Oracle Fusion Middleware

Platform: ...

You can download the Infrastructure Software from the group "Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c Media Pack".